# How to unpack LUTs into logic cells in verilog

Tags: verilog, yosys

I have a structural verilog containing LUTS all over him.

I want this verilog to be unpacked so that I'll have the same functional but instead LUTS - I'll have logic cell (Like Or/And/Xor etc...).

How can I do it ?

Does Yosys has something built in ?
Is there something else out there over the internet who already implement that kind of thing ?
Because I searched for this and I could not find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following

```
read_verilog struct.v lut.v
hierarchy -top top
flatten
synth -noabc
```

in Yosys, where lut.v contains a Verilog model of the LUT primitive. This would convert LUTs to non-optimised logic. You could also use abc (remove -noabc, or add abc at the end of the script) to optimise the logic.

Comment: It seems that it won't work for Xilinx structural verilog. Do you have another solution ?

Comment: For the last command I receive this following error :
"Module '\VCC' referenced in module '\TOP' in cell '\low.inst.VCC' is not part of the design."

Also, I used Xilinx's simprims.v (instead of lut.v) to describe my primitives

Comment: ok I found the LUT1.v, LUT2.v etc... and I try to load them. but I receive syntax error. Have any ideas why or what to do ?

Comment: The Xilinx primitive library is intended for simulation, not a synthesis type fronted like Yosys. Use Yosys' own cell library inside (`read_verilog +/xilinx/cells_sim.v`) instead.